# Need a script to do a couple simple things

Tags: batch-file, copy

I'm not good at coding, but learn quickly - it's a good thing I don't make my money doing this!.

I do computer repair (mostly malware and virus repairs) and I use a new program on my USB stick that leaves reports at the root of the customer's system drive regardless of what letter that drive occupies. (this part is automated by the program itself and isn't part of my batch script)

I want to copy my own icon to this folder, and then copy the folder to the customer's desktop and then change the folder icon to my own icon that was previously copied back in step 1.
I have done this for years manually, but since I've been using this new utility, I see the possibility of automating this process and saving me a minute of work. (every minute counts!)

I do this for 2 reasons:

1. So the customer can see what kinds of viruses/malware was found and the amount of work that was done
2. In hopes that the customer will go through the logs and see the things they downloaded or accidentally installed and will be more aware in the future. (this never works, but at least I've made an effort to help educate!)

This is what I've got so far: (sorry for the REMs, they're there so I can keep things straight in my head)
I have my icon in the same directory that the script is run from.

```
    REM THIS COPIES MY ICON TO THE DEFAULT REPORTS FOLDER AT THE ROOT OF THE CUSTOMER'S SYSTEM DRIVE AND THEN COPIES THE ENTIRE FOLDER OVER TO THE CUSTOMER'S DESKTOP
copy applogo.ico "%systemdrive%\Computer Support\"
xcopy "%systemdrive%\Computer Support" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Computer Support" /e /c /i /h /r /k /y /z

CD %userprofile%\Desktop\Computer Support

REM THIS ADDS THE SYSTEM FILE ATTRIBUTE
ATTRIB +s "Computer Support"


REM THIS CHANGES THE FOLDER ICON TO MY OWN ICON
ECHO [.ShellClassInfo] >> desktop.txt
ECHO ConfirmFileOp=0 >> desktop.txt
ECHO NoSharing=1 >> desktop.txt
ECHO IconFile=applogo.ico >> desktop.txt
ECHO IconIndex=0 >> desktop.txt
ECHO InfoTip= >> desktop.txt
CHCP 1252 >NUL
CMD.EXE /D /A /C (SET/P=ÿþ)<NUL > desktop.ini 2>NUL
CMD.EXE /D /U /C TYPE desktop.txt >> desktop.ini
DEL /F /Q desktop.txt
ATTRIB +S +H desktop.ini applogo.ico
```

This successfully copies the original folder from the root of the customer's system drive to their desktop, and it also copies my logo over too - but it doesn't change the desktop folder icon to my applogo.ico, nor does it hide the `desktop.ini` and `applogo.ico` files.

***EDIT:  After playing with the ATTRIB function, I added this and it works to hide applogo.ico separately from desktop.ini and BOTH are now hidden - still doesn't change the folder icon to my icon...

```
REM THIS ADDS THE SYSTEM FILE ATTRIBUTE
ATTRIB +S "Computer Support"
ATTRIB +S +H applogo.ico
```

So can someone see what I've done wrong?

Thank you in advance!!

***EDIT:  (the answer)

Sorry to reply to my own topic, but this can be considered CLOSED now - it's been figured out.

It finally worked with the inclusion of a PUSHD command.

Check and compare (for anyone that wanted to know)

```
REM THIS COPIES MY ICON TO THE DEFAULT REPORTS FOLDER AT THE ROOT OF THE CUSTOMER'S SYSTEM DRIVE
copy /y applogo.ico "%systemdrive%\Computer Support"

xcopy "%systemdrive%\Computer Support" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Computer Support" /e /c /i /h /r /k /y /z

REM THIS ADDS THE SYSTEM FILE ATTRIBUTE
pushd "%userprofile%\Desktop"
ATTRIB +S "Computer Support"
CD "Computer Support"
ATTRIB +S +H applogo.ico

REM THIS CHANGES THE FOLDER ICON TO MY OWN ICON
ECHO [.ShellClassInfo] >> desktop.txt
ECHO ConfirmFileOp=0 >> desktop.txt
ECHO NoSharing=1 >> desktop.txt
ECHO IconFile=applogo.ico >> desktop.txt
ECHO IconIndex=0 >> desktop.txt
ECHO InfoTip= >> desktop.txt
CHCP 1252 >NUL
CMD.EXE /D /A /C (SET/P=ÿþ)<NUL > desktop.ini 2>NUL
CMD.EXE /D /U /C TYPE desktop.txt >> desktop.ini
DEL /F /Q desktop.txt
ATTRIB +S +H desktop.ini
```

The folder now gets transferred, the folder icon gets changed, and the icon and desktop ini files are both hidden.

The addition of PUSHD of the directory *BEFORE* the ATTRIB function did the trick.
Thanks to all who looked, I hope this helps someone else do the same things I was looking to do myself.

Comment: `desktop.ini` is UTF-16 file format.

Comment: Sorry to reply to my own topic, but this can be considered CLOSED now - it's been figured out.

It finally worked with the inclusion of a PUSHD command.

See my **EDIT:  in the OP for the answer.

Comment: @user3400030: put your solution into a new answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer:

```
REM THIS COPIES MY ICON TO THE DEFAULT REPORTS FOLDER AT THE ROOT OF THE CUSTOMER'S SYSTEM DRIVE
copy /y applogo.ico "%systemdrive%\Computer Support"

xcopy "%systemdrive%\Computer Support" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Computer Support" /e /c /i /h /r /k /y /z

REM THIS ADDS THE SYSTEM FILE ATTRIBUTE
pushd "%userprofile%\Desktop"
ATTRIB +S "Computer Support"
CD "Computer Support"
ATTRIB +S +H applogo.ico

REM THIS CHANGES THE FOLDER ICON TO MY OWN ICON
ECHO [.ShellClassInfo] >> desktop.txt
ECHO ConfirmFileOp=0 >> desktop.txt
ECHO NoSharing=1 >> desktop.txt
ECHO IconFile=applogo.ico >> desktop.txt
ECHO IconIndex=0 >> desktop.txt
ECHO InfoTip= >> desktop.txt
CHCP 1252 >NUL
CMD.EXE /D /A /C (SET/P=ÿþ)<NUL > desktop.ini 2>NUL
CMD.EXE /D /U /C TYPE desktop.txt >> desktop.ini
DEL /F /Q desktop.txt
ATTRIB +S +H desktop.ini
```

I hope this helps out anyone looking to do what I was trying to do!  Works PERFECTLY.